# Removing Material Design Lite Button Hover Effect

Tags: mobile, material-design-lite

I am using Material Design lite in my mobile app.

With the buttons, the hover effect is added when it is touched, but it doesn't go away until another press is recorded.

With buttons as links this isn't too bad, but for a button that does an action, it doesn't look that good.

Is there a way to remove the hover effect after a period of time (EG 500ms)?

I have looked at removing the effect, but the lack of feedback doesn't help. Perhaps triggering a click on an unused part of the screen might work.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The answer below was a solution to a similar problem on the desktop, but it does not seem to be a fix for mobile platforms.

Also, development of Google's [Material Design Lite](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite) is now in limited support (as of Dec. 2016), in favour of their newer [Material Components for the Web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web), which still seems to be in early development. Their [current button demo](http://material-components-web.appspot.com/button.html) still has the same behaviour described in the post.

**Original:** *On the desktop*, the hover effect should remove itself automatically if you are using the `mdl-js-button` class. Here's a quick example:

```html
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button">
  Button with JS
</button>

<button class="mdl-button">
  Button without JS
</button>

<!-- Remember to include the MDL JavaScript code -->
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLjse1ef/)